# sed insert spaces between digits for long numbers

Tags: regex, sed

How one can exploit sed to insert spaces between every three digits but **only if a number is longer than 10 digits**, ie:

```
blahaaaaaa goog sdd 234 3242423
ala el 213123123123 
1231231313123 i 14124124141411
```

should turn into:

```
blahaaaaaa goog sdd 234 3242423
ala el 213 123 123 123
123 123 131 312 3 i 141 241 241 414 11
```

I can easily separate 3-digits numbers using `sed 's/[0-9]\{3\}/& /g'` but cannot combine that with a number length.

Comment: Is using `awk` an option?

Comment: I would prefer `sed` but, yeah, `awk` is good second choice.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/\d{10,}/$&=~s|\d{3}|$& |gr/ge' file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single (GNU) `sed` command could be enough:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{10,})/\n&\n/g; :a; s/([ \n])([0-9]{3})([0-9]+\n)/\1\2 \3/; ta; s/\n//g' file
```

**Update:**

**Walter A** suggested a bit more concise `sed` expression which works fine if I haven't overlooked something:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{10,})/&\n/g; :a; s/([0-9]{3})([0-9]+\n)/\1 \2/; ta; s/\n//g' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `-E` flag instructs the `sed` to use the extended regular expression syntax (to get rid of escape slashes before `(){}+` characters).
- `s/([0-9]{10,})/&\n/g` appends a new-line (`\n`) character to all digit sequences with 10 or more digits. This is in order to differentiate the digit sequences we are dealing with. The `\n` is a safe choice here because it cannot occur in the pattern space as read from the input line since it is the delimiter terminating the line. Notice that we are processing a single line per cycle (ie, since no multiline techniques are used, `\n` can be used as an anchor without interfering with other characters in the line).
- `:a; s/([0-9]{3})([0-9]+\n)/\1 \2/; ta` This is a *loop*. `:a` is a label and could be any word (the `:` indicates the label). `ta` means jump to the label `a` if the last substitution (`s` command) is successful. The `s` command here repeatedly (because it is the body of the *loop*) replaces, from left to right, a 3-digit sequence with the same 3 digits concatenated by a space character, only if this 3-digit sequence is immediately followed by one or more digits delimited by a `\n` character, until no substitution is possible.
- `s/\n//g` removes all `\n` instances from the resultant pattern space. They have been used as an anchor, or marker, to delimit the end of the digit sequences with more than or equal to 10 characters. Their mission has been completed now.

Comment: +1. An explanation would be useful. Is  `sed -E 's/([0-9]{10,})/&\n/g; :a; s/([0-9]{3})([0-9]+\n)/\1 \2/; ta; s/\n//g' file` also working?

Comment: @WalterA I updated my answer with your solution and explanation of your solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to meet a complex set of requirements like this, it is more convenient to use `perl`:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\d{10,}/$&=~s|\d{3}|$& |gr/ge' file
```

Here,

- `\d{10,}` - matches 10 or more consecutive digits
- `$&=~s|\d{3}|$& |gr` - takes the whole match (the 10+ digit substring) and replaces every 3-digit chunk (matched with `\d{3}`) with this match (since `$&` is the placeholder for the whole match) and a space. `g` is used to perform as many replacements as there are matches in the input, and `r` is used to return substitution and leave the original string untouched.
- `ge` - this flag combination means the all matches will be replaced (`g`), and `e` is necessary since the replacement string here is a regular expression to be evaluated.

Comment: I appreciate this even if no-one else does

Comment: I supposed that `sed` could be not enough... If there are not other answers, I will edit my question to make it taking into account `perl` and will accept your solution. Thanks for thorough description!

Comment: I decided to accept the answer based on my sed starting point, but anyway, your solution encourages me to lear perl - thanks!

Comment: @Pawel Note these solutions are different. This one makes sure spaces are only added when there are 10 or more digit chunks in a longer text anywhere inside it.

Comment: @Wiktor I cannot understand. Could you please give an example when the accepted solution would not work? I checked it for the text from my question and a few more and it looks ok.

Comment: @Pawel To show you some difference, see [Walter's approach demo](https://ideone.com/DVdM5C) and [my approach demo](https://ideone.com/Kss4GM). Note that it is easy with Perl to further apply more restrictions and precise the pattern. The main difference is that my solution does not need additional pre- and post-processing, and does not depend on whitespaces/newlines between "words".

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\!|sed -Ef - file
/[[:digit:]]{10,}/{
  s//\n&\n/
  h
  s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/
  s/.{3}\B/& /g
  G
  s/(.*)(\n.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/
  D
}
!
```

Determine if the current line has any 10 or more digit numbers and if so process them.

Surround the first such number by newlines.

Copy the whole line to the hold space (HS).

Remove everything except the number from the current line.

Space the number every 3 digits (only do so if there is a following digit).

Append the original line from HS to the current line.

Replace the original number by the spaced number and remove all introduced newlines except the first.

Delete the introduced newline  and thus repeat the process.

N.B. The `D` command removes upto and including the first newline in the current line i.e. the pattern space. If there is no newline, it acts the same as the `d` command. However if there is a newline, once it has removed the text before and including the newline, if there is further text it begins a new cycle but does not read in another line from the input. Thus it treats whatever remains in the pattern space as if it has read in a another line of input and starts the sed cycle again. By inserting a newline and then using `D` command it is identical to `:a;...;ba`.

Or if you prefer:

```
sed -E '/[[:digit:]]{10,}/{s//\n&\n/;h;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;s/.{3}\B/& /g;G;s/(.*)(\n.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;D}' file
```

An alternative that just uses the pattern space:

```
sed -E '/[[:digit:]]{10,}/{s//\n&\n/;s/(.*)(\n.*)(\n.*)/\1\3\2/;:a;s/^(.*\n.*\n([[:digit:]]{3} )*[[:digit:]]{3}\B)/\1 /;ta;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\n\1\3\2/;D}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

preprocess and postprocess the file:

```
tr "\n " "\r\n" < "${file}" | sed -r '/[0-9]{10}/ s/[0-9]{3}/& /g'  | tr '\r\n' '\n '
```

Comment: Ok, I accept this answer as by far simplest and still based on my sed starting point. Other answers, even if they are more sed-purist, exploit the same concept but in much more complicated (meaning "hard to follow") way. Thanks to all of you for your help!

Comment: @Pawel This will convert, for instance,`1234567890+1234` into `123 456 789 0+123 4`. Notice that `1234` is also grouped though it is less than ten digits. It will do the same even if you replace the`+` with a tab character.